# regex to find vanity URLs from IIS rewrite rules

Tags: regex

I need to extract all the vanity URLs redirect rules but exclude the redirect rules.

```
    <rule name="welcome2020" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="welcome2020" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mywebsite.org/Pages/.welcome2020aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Page to Page Redirect">
      <match url="/Staff/Pages/Ashley.aspx" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="services/Staff/Pages/Ashley.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

i need to match all `<match url="whatever" />` types that don't contain `.aspx` The only thing I have figured out is that I will need a negative lookahead. but not sure how to implement it.

I basically need something like this, but for my redirect rules.
https://www.regextester.com/15

Comment: Probably, `<match url="\.aspx$" negate="true"/>` will suffice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not in the rule itself. I have exported the rewrite rules to a file, in that file, i need to capture only the vanity rules and exclude page to page redirects..

Comment: Please add the regex you tried to make it all clearer.  What tool are you working in?

Comment: You say you try `^((?!badword).)*$`, but it matches a *string* that has no `badword`. You seem to want to match strings that start with `<match url="` + no badword + `" />`. Try removing the anchors and use the right context instead. Note you will probably have to account for the right quotation marks, replace `.` with `[^"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try:

```
^(?=.*match)(?!.*\.aspx).*
```

Please see the **[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bjhAvg/4/)** :)